# Enable right click on image on product detail page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using a customized version of the rwd Madison Island theme, by default it has been set up to not allow right clicking on the product detail page zoom image so that it can be saved.

Here is a demo site of the default functionality.
http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/women/tops-blouses/nolita-cami-490.html. 
A client wants to make it clickable by default. Everyone seems to want to disable this feature so I am pretty sure I am the first one to ask how to enable it.
The js file that deals with the image zoom is in the **js/varien/product.js** folder. I have included the section that deals with product zoom below. I have been trying to figure out which part of this file is disabling the right click ability but so far no luck.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

```
Product.Zoom = Class.create();
/**
 * Image zoom control
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
Product.Zoom.prototype = {
    initialize: function(imageEl, trackEl, handleEl, zoomInEl, zoomOutEl, hintEl){
        this.containerEl = $(imageEl).parentNode;
        this.imageEl = $(imageEl);
        this.handleEl = $(handleEl);
        this.trackEl = $(trackEl);
        this.hintEl = $(hintEl);

        this.containerDim = Element.getDimensions(this.containerEl);
        this.imageDim = Element.getDimensions(this.imageEl);

        this.imageDim.ratio = this.imageDim.width/this.imageDim.height;

        this.floorZoom = 1;

        if (this.imageDim.width > this.imageDim.height) {
            this.ceilingZoom = this.imageDim.width / this.containerDim.width;
        } else {
            this.ceilingZoom = this.imageDim.height / this.containerDim.height;
        }

        if (this.imageDim.width <= this.containerDim.width
            && this.imageDim.height <= this.containerDim.height) {
            this.trackEl.up().hide();
            this.hintEl.hide();
            this.containerEl.removeClassName('product-image-zoom');
            return;
        }

        this.imageX = 0;
        this.imageY = 0;
        this.imageZoom = 1;

        this.sliderSpeed = 0;
        this.sliderAccel = 0;
        this.zoomBtnPressed = false;

        this.showFull = false;

        this.selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

        this.draggable = new Draggable(imageEl, {
            starteffect:false,
            reverteffect:false,
            endeffect:false,
            snap:this.contain.bind(this)
        });

        this.slider = new Control.Slider(handleEl, trackEl, {
            axis:'horizontal',
            minimum:0,
            maximum:Element.getDimensions(this.trackEl).width,
            alignX:0,
            increment:1,
            sliderValue:0,
            onSlide:this.scale.bind(this),
            onChange:this.scale.bind(this)
        });

        this.scale(0);

        Event.observe(this.imageEl, 'dblclick', this.toggleFull.bind(this));

        Event.observe($(zoomInEl), 'mousedown', this.startZoomIn.bind(this));
        Event.observe($(zoomInEl), 'mouseup', this.stopZooming.bind(this));
        Event.observe($(zoomInEl), 'mouseout', this.stopZooming.bind(this));

        Event.observe($(zoomOutEl), 'mousedown', this.startZoomOut.bind(this));
        Event.observe($(zoomOutEl), 'mouseup', this.stopZooming.bind(this));
        Event.observe($(zoomOutEl), 'mouseout', this.stopZooming.bind(this));
    },

    toggleFull: function () {
        this.showFull = !this.showFull;

        //Hide selects for IE6 only
        if (typeof document.body.style.maxHeight == "undefined")  {
            for (i=0; i<this.selects.length; i++) {
                this.selects[i].style.visibility = this.showFull ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
            }
        }
        val_scale = !this.showFull ? this.slider.value : 1;
        this.scale(val_scale);

        this.trackEl.style.visibility = this.showFull ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
        this.containerEl.style.overflow = this.showFull ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        this.containerEl.style.zIndex = this.showFull ? '1000' : '9';

        return this;
    },

    scale: function (v) {
        var centerX  = (this.containerDim.width*(1-this.imageZoom)/2-this.imageX)/this.imageZoom;
        var centerY  = (this.containerDim.height*(1-this.imageZoom)/2-this.imageY)/this.imageZoom;
        var overSize = (this.imageDim.width > this.containerDim.width || this.imageDim.height > this.containerDim.height);

        this.imageZoom = this.floorZoom+(v*(this.ceilingZoom-this.floorZoom));

        if (overSize) {
            if (this.imageDim.width > this.imageDim.height) {
                this.imageEl.style.width = (this.imageZoom*this.containerDim.width)+'px';
            } else {
                this.imageEl.style.height = (this.imageZoom*this.containerDim.height)+'px';
            }
            if (this.containerDim.ratio) {
                if (this.imageDim.width > this.imageDim.height) {
                    this.imageEl.style.height = (this.imageZoom*this.containerDim.width*this.containerDim.ratio)+'px'; // for safari
                } else {
                    this.imageEl.style.width = (this.imageZoom*this.containerDim.height*this.containerDim.ratio)+'px'; // for safari
                }
            }
        } else {
            this.slider.setDisabled();
        }

        this.imageX = this.containerDim.width*(1-this.imageZoom)/2-centerX*this.imageZoom;
        this.imageY = this.containerDim.height*(1-this.imageZoom)/2-centerY*this.imageZoom;

        this.contain(this.imageX, this.imageY, this.draggable);

        return true;
    },

    startZoomIn: function()
    {
        if (!this.slider.disabled) {
            this.zoomBtnPressed = true;
            this.sliderAccel = .002;
            this.periodicalZoom();
            this.zoomer = new PeriodicalExecuter(this.periodicalZoom.bind(this), .05);
        }
        return this;
    },

    startZoomOut: function()
    {
        if (!this.slider.disabled) {
            this.zoomBtnPressed = true;
            this.sliderAccel = -.002;
            this.periodicalZoom();
            this.zoomer = new PeriodicalExecuter(this.periodicalZoom.bind(this), .05);
        }
        return this;
    },

    stopZooming: function()
    {
        if (!this.zoomer || this.sliderSpeed==0) {
            return;
        }
        this.zoomBtnPressed = false;
        this.sliderAccel = 0;
    },

    periodicalZoom: function()
    {
        if (!this.zoomer) {
            return this;
        }

        if (this.zoomBtnPressed) {
            this.sliderSpeed += this.sliderAccel;
        } else {
            this.sliderSpeed /= 1.5;
            if (Math.abs(this.sliderSpeed)<.001) {
                this.sliderSpeed = 0;
                this.zoomer.stop();
                this.zoomer = null;
            }
        }
        this.slider.value += this.sliderSpeed;

        this.slider.setValue(this.slider.value);
        this.scale(this.slider.value);

        return this;
    },

    contain: function (x,y,draggable) {

        var dim = Element.getDimensions(draggable.element);

        var xMin = 0, xMax = this.containerDim.width-dim.width;
        var yMin = 0, yMax = this.containerDim.height-dim.height;

        x = x>xMin ? xMin : x;
        x = x<xMax ? xMax : x;
        y = y>yMin ? yMin : y;
        y = y<yMax ? yMax : y;

        if (this.containerDim.width > dim.width) {
            x = (this.containerDim.width/2) - (dim.width/2);
        }

        if (this.containerDim.height > dim.height) {
            y = (this.containerDim.height/2) - (dim.height/2);
        }

        this.imageX = x;
        this.imageY = y;

        this.imageEl.style.left = this.imageX+'px';
        this.imageEl.style.top = this.imageY+'px';

        return [x,y];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `zoom` image you're seeing only shows when you hover over the original image. That being said, when you move your mouse towards the `zoom`, it disappears.

There's a div inside the class `zoomWindowContainer` near the bottom of your code when using `inspect` - it has no class currently, but one could be added (probably in the media.phtml file in your `/app/design/frontend/(theme)/(package)/catalog/product/view` folder.

Your current images don't fill the width of the image gallery area, so changing the `left` styling to `0` will not push the zoom preview to the far left top corner of your product image.

Your image previews are showing at 500px wide and 750px in height (in my screen - may be smaller for others). Using this same `height and width` for the `zoomWindowContainer`'s subclass you created will cover the entire image.

From there you'll have your mouse over the `zoom` image which should make it clickable.

---

Alternatively, look into free image/gallery extensions that provide a popup image instead of the hover-over you see now. Hover is Desktop exclusive and IMO shouldn't be made standard so that mobile is just as responsive.